# React Native: TypeError: undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-native

I need some help to fix an error in my code that appears on my console. though it does not appear on the screen and I can still edit the field and save to the database but every time it mounted the same error appears. I tried to put Try/catch because of the promise rejection error but the type error is still there. I don't know what is wrong with my code.

```
 TypeError: undefined is not an object  (evaluating 'dbUser.firstname')
 TypeError: undefined is not an object  (evaluating '_dbUser$avatar.uri')
```

sample code below

```
 MountFirestore = async () => {
  try {
    const curUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    const { email } = curUser;

    const dbUser =
     await firebase
         .firestore()
         .collection('users')
         .doc(curUser.uid)
         .get()
         .then(doc => {
             if (!doc.exists) {
             console.log('No such document!');
             } else {          
             console.log(doc.id, doc.data());

           const {
           firstname,
           lastname,
           email,
           avatar: {uri, mime, dateModified}} = doc.data();

           this.setState({
           firstname, 
           lastname,
           email,
           avatar: {uri, mime, dateModified},
           loading: false
           })
       }
      return doc;
  })
  .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting document', err);
  });

  const {
     firstname, lastname,
     avatar: {uri, mime, dateModified}} = dbUser;

  this.setState({
     firstname,
     lastname,
     email,
     avatar: {uri, mime, dateModified}, 
     loading: true
  }); 
 }
 catch (error) {
  console.log(error.toString(error));
 } 
};
```

sample console error[console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHeep.jpg)

---

### edited:

I found the solution. for the typeerror undefined. I removed const dbuser and setstate. Doing it like below solve all the errors.

```
  MountFirestore = async () => {
   try {
    const curUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;

     await firebase
         .firestore()
         .collection('users')
         .doc(curUser.uid)
         .get()
         .then(doc => {
             if (!doc.exists) {
             console.log('No such document!');
             } else {          
             console.log(doc.id, doc.data());

           const {
           firstname,
           lastname,
           email,
           avatar: {uri, mime, dateModified}} = doc.data();

           this.setState({
           firstname, 
           lastname,
           email,
           avatar: {uri, mime, dateModified},
           loading: false
           })
       }
      return doc;
      })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting document', err);
    });

     this.setState({loading: true})
   }
   catch (error) {
     console.log(error.toString(error));
   } 
 };
```

Comment: In the final `.then()` function when you query the DB, you need to `return doc;` at the end, otherwise `dbUser` is `undefined` because the function doesn't return anything.

Comment: you use `await` in your function but not set this function as `async`.Your function must be `MountFirestore = async () => {...}`

Comment: sorry i removed the await already in my code. I will try to put the return doc thanks for the help

Comment: return.doc; works thanks but the other one TypeError: undefined is not an object  (evaluating '_dbUser$avatar.uri') is still appearing. uri is a subfield of avatar

Comment: If you remove `await`, `dbUser` will store the Promise, not the user. Because without `await`, the rest of your code will run *while the query runs*, not after. Keep the `await` and add the `async` as suggested.

Comment: I did put async and await similar to the edited sample above but the TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_dbUser$avatar.uri')  is still appearing which is a subfield, but the other errors are already gone

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(doc.id, doc.data());`?

Comment: MK0wf78jCXPZNvQnNSud5vdgNds2 {"accountCreatedDate": {"nanoseconds": 755000000, "seconds": 1584849085}, "accountModifiedDate": {"nanoseconds": 495000000, "seconds": 1585291797}, "avatar": {"dateModified": {"nanoseconds": 70000000, "seconds": 1585461905}, "mime": "image/jpeg", "uri": "file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/718803be-d2a1-4130-a9e8-0b6ba1a8e6c9.jpg"}, "email": "ree@ree.ko", "firstname": "Threela", "lastLoginDate": {"nanoseconds": 196000000, "seconds": 1585559173}, "lastname": "Lalala"}

Comment: I posted an image for the sample error above, below the code